# Código para acrescentar um valor a células com números e devolva uma fórmula =valorinicial+valoracrescentado não funciona para números decimais

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Quero que a minha macro acrescente um valor a uma célula que já contenha um número. Por exemplo: uma célula com valor 1, quero acrescentar 1, o resultado irá aparecer 2 mas quero que desta adição resulte a fórmula =1+1 e não apenas o número 2.

Pedi ao chatGPT para me criar um código que fizesse isto e após várias correções o problema persiste, apenas consigo usar a macro em números inteiros, números decimais não funciona.

Nenhuma maneira que tentei funciona sem ser para números inteiros, por isso partilho o código em baixo se alguém me conseguir ajudar.

Sub Adicionar_1_7()

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Selection ' Define o intervalo como as células selecionadas

For Each cell In rng

    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then

        cell.Value = cell.Value & "+ 1.7"

    Else

        MsgBox "A célula " & cell.Address & " não contém um valor numérico.\"

    End If

Next cell

Exit Sub
```

ErrorHandler:

```
MsgBox "Erro " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
```

End Sub

Já tentei mudar a localização das aspas, colocar o resultado como string, função que permite números decimais funcionar. Não é que seja algo imperativo mas chateia-me não conseguir resolver este problema. Não sou de informática portanto tenho muito poucos conhecimentos de programação, se alguém conseguir ajudar agradecia.

Comment: cara, é o seguinte, eu não entendo nada de vba, mas será que não está tentando fazer operações aritméticas com `string` vulgo texto, ao invés de utilizar valores decimais (numéricos)?

Comment: Peço desculpa pela minha ignorância, mas como é que diferencio isso?
Se eu pegar numa célula vazia no documento, escrever 1, o código funciona, se escrever 1.1 já dá erro.

Comment: E se escrever `1,1`? Usando vírgula em vez de ponto? A depender das configurações, o Excel reconhecerá diferentes marcadores de decimais (no meu caso, por exemplo, tenho que usar vírgula, e não ponto).

Comment: O meu excel está configurado para o separador decimal ser ponto. No entanto já tentei mudar para virgula e mudar no código os separadores para virgulas e o problema mantém-se